# BaseX: database size is not being updated when deleting nodes

Tags: basex

I am running baseX 8.4.4 on my server and using the web-app for administration.

Now, when i delete nodes (via JAVA), the database-size shown in the webapp is not updating.

Is this just a bug of the GUI or is baseX somehow storing invisible backups? (as no backups are visible (see figure). Or are  there other files needing this memory? All the Logs have been deleted.

[image: database-view of the webapp-GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact kind of update operation you are performing, the database may only shrink after an optimize call.